# TDengine database filtering a query by timestamp

Tags: tdengine

From the screenshot, as you can see, there is data in my table `t1`. And I want to filter the query with the same timestamp in `t1`, but there is no result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be caused by the timezone setting of your local environment. You should double-check if the timezone in your taos.cfg file which is under /etc/taos/ for Linux env and compare it with your machine timezone by the command `date`. If those do not match, then you should make it the same.